# How to setup Logstash JDBC output to write JSON field?

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

I want to stream data from LogStash to a MS SQL Server working table with a schema something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkingTable] (
    [MessageId] bigint,       //Auto Incrementing primary key.
    [Data]      nvarchar(MAX) //JSON data.
)
```

I want the `[Data]` field to contain the entire message from LogStash, serialized as a JSON string, and don't want to half to use sprintf to format it explicitly.

How can this be done using the JDBC output plugin or perhaps some other plugin?

Comment: I have never used the jdbc output, but perhaps the [json codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html) might help?

Comment: @baudsp Thank you yes this is what I believe will be needed! If nobody beats me to it I will post an answer that demonstrates this solution.

Comment: Spoke too soon.. no support for codecs in the logstash-output-jdbc plugin. I was also looking at json_encode filter but it seems to support encoding single fields only, and not an entire event.

Comment: Have you tried the unofficlal plugin : https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

```
output {
jdbc {
    driver_jar_path => 'jar file path'
    connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver:port;databaseName=databaseName;user=user;password=pass"
    enable_event_as_json_keyword => true
    statement => ["INSERT INTO [dbo].[WorkingTable] (MessageId, Data) VALUES(?, ?)", "%{[Data][MessageId]}", "@event"]
}}
```

You should set enable_event_as_json_keyword to true and then use the magic @event in the statement